# Response properly when changing innerWidth in an event handler with vanilla Js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I desire to change the `innerHTML` of an element when the viewport becomes smaller than 1024pxs.

I ought to do so without any jQuery, only with vanilla Js.

So far I tried these solutions:

```
(function changeTextualName() {

if (window.innerWidth <= 1024) {
    document.querySelector(".logo-text a").innerHTML = "example1 <br> example2";
} else {
    document.querySelector(".logo-text a").innerHTML = "example1 | Example2";
}

}());
```

This first solution worked only partially: It did work the first time the webpage wed loaded, but not on resizes (the "event" in the philosophical meaning of the sense due to the lack of an event listener, won't be cleared).

I also tried this solution, which doesn't work at all:

```
(function changeTextualName() {

window.addEventListener("innerWidth <= 1024", function() {
        document.querySelector(".logo-text a").innerHTML = "example1 <br> Example2";
}

}());
```

As a newcomer I miss something with the logic. I kept reading listening to resize events and didn't see any code example dealing with values like 1024 or whatever. Maybe jQuery (or creating a library from a scratch - something I have no intention to do in this case) is a must after all?

Update for Saar:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dn8ru.png)

Comment: you have a small mistake, the event listener should listen to "resize" window.addEventListener('resize',function(){// your code});

Comment: Thanks to Saar's comments & answer I understand my mistake: I called the function once, in webpage bootstrapping, and didn't initiate the callback concept properly so there wasn't a callback on each resize. I thank Saar for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call your method in the event listener of 'resize'

```js
function changeTextualName() {

if (window.innerWidth <= 1024) {
    document.querySelector(".logo-text a").innerHTML = "example1 <br> example2";
} else {
    document.querySelector(".logo-text a").innerHTML = "example1 | Example2";
}
window.addEventListener('resize',changeTextualName);
```

Comment: Oh, I understand my mistake: I called the function once, in webpage bootstrapping, and didn't initiate the callback concept properly so there wasn't a callback on each resize. Thanks to you I understand my mistake.

Comment: happy to help :)

Comment: In your changeTextualName function only do alert(1); and see if it's called.

Comment: Yes it is. If you now go to the site it is.

Comment: The problem is with your querySelector, in the console it shows you receive null

Comment: your 2nd querySelector is missing a dot, should be (".logo-text a") instead of ("logo-text a")

Comment: Sorry, had a typo there. Stressful day, very hard year of my life, much confusion. either way I should work with an IDE instead a simple text editor.